# make network requests seem to be coming from the tethered PC not from the mobile device

Tags: networking, tethering

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask question..but sorry if it's not. At our work, we have a product hosted in our office network and we use VPN on Windows PCs to connect to it. We need to test this product on safari ios and chrome android. I could just test this product on android chrome, without any problem, using android simulator for windows. But I cannot do the same with ios since there's no ios simulator for windows. My question is, is there a way for me to make the server thinks that requests from my ios devices is coming from my windows PC that has VPN already set up? I've tried reverse tethering but the server refuses my connection probably because of differences in MAC address.